# Using multiple queries (only one is working)

Tags: php, sql

i would like to allow multiple users to login according to their userID and forward each user to his page. However only the last if condition works.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "clinic system");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $idname = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query1 = "SELECT *     FROM users WHERE UID='".$idname."' AND pass= '".$password."' AND User_type_id= '1'";
    $query2= "SELECT *  FROM users WHERE UID='".$idname."' AND pass= '".$password."' AND User_type_id= '2'";
    $query3= "SELECT *  FROM users WHERE UID='".$idname."' AND pass= '".$password."' AND User_type_id= '3'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);

    if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        $_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['name'];
        header("location:Dr.html");
    }

    if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['name'];
        header("location:Assis.html");
    }

    if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
        $_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['name'];
        header("location:Recep.html");
    }
    else{
      header("location:stafflog.php?Invalid=  please enter correct ID or Password");
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Why do 3 queries? Do `SELECT user_type_id FROM users WHERE ...`

Comment: You should add `exit;` after each header also. That hasn't been addressed.

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You only need to retrieve the `User_type_id` from the database and then decide on that which page to go to...

```
$query1 = "SELECT *     FROM users WHERE UID='".$idname."' AND pass= '".$password."'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    $_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['name'];
    if ( $row['User_type_id'] == 1 )  {
        header("location:Dr.html");
    }
    if ( $row['User_type_id'] == 2 )  {
        header("location:Assis.html");
    }
    if ( $row['User_type_id'] == 3 )  {
        header("location:Recep.html");
    }
    exit;
}
```

Although a couple of major points - you should be using prepared statements - [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Also you should not be storing plain text passwords, have a read of [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)

Comment: I'd use a `switch` statement since you're comparing the same value each time. Or at least use `elseif`.

Answer (score -2):

you dont need to have 3 queries for this. why dont you just save a column in the database called "userTypeID" and have it be a int. then when a user logs in check the table and save the number in the session. this can be done easily in 1 query.

also i believe you are exposed to sql injection. you should use prepared statements.

Comment: You mean column, not row.